# How to remove anaconda3 completely via terminal?

Tags: python, uninstall, anaconda

I have issues installing anaconda3 on my mac. The conda prompt doesn't work and I've had issues to edit it in my .bash_profile too. So I want to remove everything that has to do with anaconda and conda. But how can I do that? Already tried *rm -rf ~/anaconda3.*

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf anaconda3` will not work because anaconda is not installed in `user/xyz/anaconda3`.

Use the ls command in terminal to work out where anaconda3 is.

For me, the following commands were required:

```
cd ..
cd ..
rm -rf anaconda3
```